# Whatever input, the answer is 67 ,why?

Tags: c, stdio

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%*2s",&a);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1351 (input to scanf)
67 (output from printf)
```

Whatever input I give,the answer is always 67. Where is the 67 coming from?

Comment: (1) Post code, not images of it. (2) When you mismatch scanf conversion specifiers to variable types, the behavior of your entire program is undefined. So 67 is as valid a result as any. Be thankful it didn't BSOD on you (it's allowed to).

Comment: Image isn't clear..post code

Comment: 1) **Don't post images of text!** 2) Read [ask]. 3) Yes, that's wrong, as we all know the answer is always `42`.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I vote for `format C:` in response to invoking UB by not following the most basic things at least.

Comment: @Olaf - I can imagine it now. The SO compiler project. "Better be careful, 'cause our UB is malicious!" :)

Comment: @StoryTeller: Slogan: "With auto-question on SO. Some questions are only asked once (because the asker`s computer is broken afterwards)"

Comment: You didn't check the return value of `scanf` so you can't know if it succesfully assigned a value or not.

Comment: @ Jonathon Reinhart Yes,scanf is not succesfully.

Answer (score 2):

To get int value from user user:

```
int a;
scanf("%d",&a);
```

scanf uses different specifiers:

%d integer

%f Float

%d double

%c char

Comment: I know this.I think @Story Teller is right.67 is ans valid a result as any.

Comment: Since you are using a variable unassigned, it is taking its old value from memory heap. To change this assign a initial value

Comment: @JingYi: For an invalid program, **every** behaviour is valid. That's what StoryTeller meant. This implies **arbitrary** and different behaviour for each run.

Answer (score 1):

In the above program, the `scanf()` reads but does not assign the value due to the `*` format specifier. As a result, whatever is the value of a (which is not initialized) is produced as output by `printf()`. In this case, 67 is the garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

The * tells scanf to read in but ignore the input. Take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ . why it always prints 67 you might need to step through a debugger to see what the int is initialized with and how that changes.

Comment: "*what the int is initialized with*" as per the code shown, it's not initialised at all, so printing it invoke undefined behaviour, anything can happen (be printed).

Comment: I was trying to suggest to explain what is being observed, you are absolutely correct that this is undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Use correct format specifiers for their respective data types

```
float          %f
double         %lf
int            %d or %i
unsigned int   %u
char           %c
char *         %s
long int       %ld
long long int  %lld
```